# Multiplicity constraint violated when I specified a hasMany relation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-migrations

I am using Entity Framework to hold a list of objects (`ReportCell`) in one `ReportRow` object. Then multiple `ReportRow` objects are kept within one Report.

The classes look like:

**Report**

```
public class Report
{
    public int ReportId { get; set; }
    public virtual List<ReportRow> ReportRows { get; set; }

    public Report()
    {            
        ReportRows = new List<ReportRow>();
    }
}
```

**ReportRow**

```
public class ReportRow
{
    public int ReportRowId { get; set; }
    public virtual List<ReportCell> ReportCells { get; set; }

    public ReportRow()
    {
        ReportCells = new List<ReportCell>();
    }
}
```

**ReportCell**

```
public class ReportCell
{
    public int ReportCellId { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

Then in Entity Framework I tell the Framework to persist these classes with Code First:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Report>().HasKey(r => r.ReportId);
modelBuilder.Entity<Report>()
            .Property(r => r.ReportId)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
modelBuilder.Entity<Report>().HasMany(rep => rep.ReportRows);

modelBuilder.Entity<ReportRow>().HasKey(rr => rr.ReportRowId);
modelBuilder.Entity<ReportRow>()
            .Property(rr => rr.ReportRowId)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
modelBuilder.Entity<ReportRow>().HasMany(rr => rr.ReportCells);

modelBuilder.Entity<ReportCell>().HasKey(rc => rc.ReportCellId);
modelBuilder.Entity<ReportCell>()
            .Property(rc => rc.ReportCellId)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
modelBuilder.Entity<ReportCell>().Property(rc => rc.Data);
```

I have an extensive database seed that populates the database after a successful migration, because Entity Framework manages to toss all my data every migration (`AutomaticDataLossAllowed = true`).
When executing the next code, I get an exception on the SaveChanges()

```
protected override void Seed(ReportModuleContext context)
{
    var cells = new List<ReportCell>();
    for (var n = 1; n <= 100; n++)
    {
           cells.Add(new ReportCell { Data = "Random data " + n, ReportCellId = n});
    }

    var rows = new List<ReportRow>();
    for (var x = 0; x < 20; x++)
    {
        var row = new ReportRow();
        row.ReportCells.Add(cells[x]);
        row.ReportCells.Add(cells[x+1]);
        row.ReportCells.Add(cells[x+2]);
        row.ReportCells.Add(cells[x+3]);
        row.ReportCells.Add(cells[x+4]);
        row.ReportRowId = x;
        rows.Add(row);
    }

    IList<Report> reports = new List<Report>();
    reports.Add(new Report
    {
        ReportId = 1,
        ReportRows = rows
    });
    reports.Add(new Report
    {
        ReportId = 2,
        ReportRows = rows
    });
    foreach (var rep in reports)
    {
        context.Reports.AddOrUpdate(rep);
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

So all it does is make some strings, use those as `Data` and add 5 cells in each row. Then add 5 rows in a report. Entity Framework then starts spitting out Exceptions:

> Multiplicity constraint violated. The role 'ReportRow_ReportCells_Source' of the relationship 'Persistance.ReportRow_ReportCells' has multiplicity 1 or 0..1.

(I have looked at all available questions asked before and have not found a satisfactory answer as of yet...)

The strange thing about the error is that I have used the `hasMany()` between `Report` and `ReportRow` and that works fine. But the same thing doesn't work between `ReportRow` and `ReportCell` ? I really hope I'm just missing something really simple, I've lost a day on this already...

Comment: Did you intend to multiply `x` by 5 in your second loop for each lookup into `cells`? Because at the moment you're trying to add `cells[4]` to 5 different rows (the first five rows you create in that loop, for `x` values between 0 and 4). I think you've then got a separate (but similar issue) where you keep assigning the *same* rows collection to multiple reports.

Comment: Oh crap, I think you're right... Edit: AAaaaaand it works. Wow. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution has been provided by Damien_The_Unbeliever.

When using the same object in 2 different objects, Entity Frameworks starts giving trouble (which I know about). A small mistake in the for loop caused objects to be used more than once. Fixing the loop fixed the issue completely.

Fixed code looks like:

```
var rows = new List<ReportRow>();
for (var x = 0; x < 20; x+=5)
{
    var row = new ReportRow();
    row.ReportCells.Add(cells[x]);
    row.ReportCells.Add(cells[x+1]);
    row.ReportCells.Add(cells[x+2]);
    row.ReportCells.Add(cells[x+3]);
    row.ReportCells.Add(cells[x+4]);
    row.ReportRowId = x;
    rows.Add(row);
}
```